# Where are the Performance counters in visual studio 2015 profiler?

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

Were performance counters removed from visual studio? I saw articles about the ability of VS profiler to measure counters like cache misses and hard faults but I can't find them when I try the profiler.

Comment: It's been a [Greek tragedy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8/) since Win8, I think they just gave up on it.